# jquery validation of reCaptcha

Tags: jquery, joomla, recaptcha

i am using the default reCaptcha plugin in joomla in my custom component. i have added the following code in my layout page:

```
<?php
JPluginHelper::importPlugin('captcha');
$dispatcher = JDispatcher::getInstance();
$dispatcher->trigger('onInit','dynamic_recaptcha_1');
```

and ...........................

```
<form ....................>
...............
<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1"></div>
</form>
```

And my jquery validation looks like this:

```
rules: {
dynamic_recaptcha_1: {
            required: true
        }
},
messages: {
                dynamic_recaptcha_1: {
              required: "Please enter the captcha value"
        }
}
```

the validation do not occur, i mean using the jquery. may i know what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

i fixed the problem myself. the field id is different and not **dynamic_recaptcha_1**. it is **recaptcha_response_field**